# How do I remove comments of files?

Tags: command-line, java, sed, text-processing

I have a dir with many files. I want to remove all the comments of that files. How do I do that?

The files looks like this (everything what is between the /* and the */ are comment):

`/*     */ import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: Are them all on a single line or they span over multiple lines?

Comment: All the lines in the files are like the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your files somewhere else first.
If as in your example the comment is on one line do

```
for file in *.java
do 
   sed -i 's|/\*[^/]*\*/||g' "$file"
done
```

Comment: This won't remove a comment like this one: `/*comment/with/slashes*/`

Comment: @kos, yes I wasnt sure if ubuntu sed did non-greedy  matches as `-E` isnt in their sed man page (but I later found `-r` is)

Answer (score 0):

Since they are always on a single line and multiple occurences on the same line seem to be excluded:

```
for f in *.java; do sed -i 's/\/\*[^*]*\*\/ \?//' "$f"; done
```

However, in case of multiple occurences on the same line:

```
for f in *.java; do sed 's/\/\*[^*]*\*\/ \?//g' "$f"; done
```

Comment: sorry: what is `-E` ? (my (gnu)sed version does not have perl's `*?` operators, do they come with -E?)

Comment: @JJoao `-E` is in GNU Sed, but it's not documented; it's just the equivalent of `-r`, much like `grep`'s `-E` it enable ERE syntax (I think it's there because `-E` is planned to be standardized by POSIX to be the standard switch to enable ERE syntax, but I'm not entirely sure). However no, that was just an error, probably I forgot to adjust a previously used Perl pattern. Thanks for having pointed that out! Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for  the information about -E; We must write a petition for non-greedy operators in sed! ☺

Comment: @JJoao Indeed! I'd sign that. However don't take for correct that information, that's what I've *heard* from a couple of users on Unix & Linux, however I couldn't find any other confirmation of this.